# file.exists() returns false, can't play my audio file

Tags: android, file, file-exists, media-type

I'm trying to play audio from storage when i click on item, for some reason file returns false for exists(), i have read and write external storage permission, and file is there and doesn't seem damaged, my file is in .mp4 format, which i will play as audio type.

this is my permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

provider:

```
<provider
        android:authorities="com.aliaskarurakov.android.mycallrecorderdemo"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

this is my method:

```
    public void playAudio(){
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tempAudioFile/temp.mp4";
        Log.d("path", "onClick: path = "+path);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File file = new File(path);
        Log.i("", "onResponse: name "+file.getName());
        if (file.exists()){
            Log.i("", "onResponse: I EXIST");
        } else {
            Log.i("", "onResponse: dont exist?");
        }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setDataAndType(getUriForFile(context,"com.aliaskarurakov.android.mycallrecorderdemo",file), "audio/*");
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: mp**4** is a *video*, not an *audio* file.

Comment: i know i can play it as an audio.

Comment: I guess you should  use , `"video/*")` instead of `, "audio/*")`

Comment: Already tried, same problem.

Comment: Try this: `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "video/*");` instead of your longer instruction.

Comment: `file.exists()` does **not** rely on file type whether video or audio. See if storage permission is **really** granted in your device's permission settings. And btw it's bad practice to concat path like this.

Comment: Moreover, since Marshmallow on, you have to request dangerous permissions at run time

Answer (score 0):

You still need to ask for the permission at runtime. Call this function where needed.

```
private void checkReadStoragePermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTENAL_STORAGE);
    }else{
        // Do your stuff here if permission is already granted by user
    }
}
```

And then handle if the user grants it or not.

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        // Here is the permission that you want
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_EXTENAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                // Do your stuff here if permission is granted by user

    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```